# Apache2 .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I want to do the following:

I have about 5 URLs which has to be redirected manuall, the rest automatic means:

These ones have to be redirected manually
www.mywebsite.com/test1 which has to be redirected to www.mywebsite.de/myfolder/test1
www.mywebsite.com/test2 which has to be redirected to www.mywebsite.de/thisisanother/folder/test2

The Rest (if none of the above) - no matter if I enter www.mywebsite.com or mywebsite.com has to be redirected to www.mywebsite.de/en/

**To sum:**
I want to hardcode two redirects for test1 and test2, because they have to be redirected to somewhere else. **The rest if not test1 or test2** have to be redirected to www.mydomain.de/en/ - how to do ???? – codeworxx 2 mins ago edit

I have no clue, where the problem is:
I have created a .htaccess file in www root of www.mywebsite.com with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule test1 http://www.mywebsite.de/myfolder/test1 [R301]
RewriteRule test2 http://www.mywebsite.de/thisisanother/folder/test2 [R301]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.de/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it does not do what I want.

If I enter mywebsite.com or www.mywebsite.com I get an Internal Server Error. If I enter www.mywebsite.com/test1 it redirects to www.mywebsite.de/en/$1 ?!?!?!?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test1
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.de/myfolder/test1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test2
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.de/thisisanother/folder/test2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(test1|test2)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.de/en/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: perfect - that worked as expected! thanks :) you saved my day!